# Can a specialist wizard cast a spell that is from both the specialized and prohibited schools?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spellcasting

I have a wizard that specialized in Conjuration. Evocation is among his prohibited schools. There is a spell called "Kelgore's Fire Bolt" (PHB2) that is marked as both Conjuration and Evocation [Fire]. According to the rules, can this specialist wizard learn and cast the spell or not?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Dual-school spells appeared only in *Player’s Handbook II* and *Dragon Magic*, and so those are the books that explain them (the explanation is the same in both).

> In all cases, treat these spells as if they belonged to both schools simultaneously. Effects that prevent a spellcaster from accessing one school of a dual-school spell prevent all access to that spell. For example, a specialist wizard cannot learn a dual-school spell if either of the spell’s schools is one of his prohibited schools.

<sup>(*Player’s Handbook II* pg. 95, *Dragon Magic* pg. 60)</sup>

So no, your wizard cannot learn or cast *Kelgore’s fire bolt* as a wizard spell. You could cast it from an item, or using *wish* or something similar, or take levels in another class that gets access to it, but as a wizard, without something exceptional, it’s not an option for you.

Comment: Damn you and your quick fingers. I just found that passage.

Comment: Does this interpretation [invalidate the answer on this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122337/dual-school-spells-for-advanced-learning-dread-necromancer?rq=1)?

Comment: @JohnP No, because advanced learning doesn’t say something crazy like “the spell must not be a non-necromancy spell,” it says it “must be a necromancy spell.” A dual-school spell with one of its schools *is* a necromancy spell, so is eligible. It’s just also something else—which is fine, nothing about advanced learning says it’s not allowed to be. Specialist wizards, on the other hand, do have something that says it’s not allowed to be from one of those schools.

Comment: You might add that it can be cast with limited wish or wish since those allow casting of spells not in one's spell list, but it cannot be learned under any circumstances.

Comment: @WannabeWarlock Yeah, I should probably reword that last sentence to not imply that those are the only ways, since I’m sure they’re not.

Comment: @KRyan thanks for an astonishingly quick and excellent answer!

Comment: @KRyan of course for wizards another way to get access to the spell would be to research a new version of the spell that belongs only to Conjuration...

Comment: @mtijn Research has no place in questions like these—research exists as a way got a DM to implement custom content they have agreed to allow, to justify why no one else does. It’s pointless to mention “of course you can just do it even though the rules say no, if the DM lets you.” That’s always true, but really disingenuous to the question asked.

Comment: One other point, a specialist wizard cannot cast prohibited schools from spell completion items including wands, scrolls, staves, or any other items that require the user to complete the spell. It could only be activated, not cast, from an item (such as keyword activation on a wondrous item)

Comment: @WannabeWarlock Use Magic Device says the wizard can.

Comment: @WannabeWarlock I explicitly said it *wasn’t* the same? Kinda confused now.

Comment: I'm confused, too. I was just referring to your answer: "You could cast it from an item ..." -- barring umd or other shenanigans, this is basically incorrect. That's all i was saying.

Comment: @WannabeWarlock I was going to mention UMD explicitly, but then decided that there probably exist items that allow you to “cast” at least some spells without UMD (I mean, *probably, right?* just based on the sheer quantity of content out there), so I figured I’d just leave it out, because you *can* cast spells from items. It might require UMD to do so, depending on the type of item, but you *can*. And all that seemed like too much to go into in that sorta-tangential sentence. As you said, though, in no case does that make it casting “as a wizard”—which is what I said too.